# C# get filtered list from Magento soap api v1.9

Tags: c#, list, magento, soap

So I have SOAP WSDL from Magento and I create a service web reference in VS2017.

I have to use vers 1.9 and so the documentation is [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/customer/customer.list.html).

The method for 'info' works well:

```
object k = magento.call(sessionID, "customer.info", "10");..... ok
```

but I cannot understand what kind of object I have to use to filter a list:

```
object k = magento.call(sessionID, "customer.list", ??filters??);
```

I've yet used `Dictonary<string, object>` but the exception says me it don't want IDictonary object.

So how can I get the list for (i.e.) *customer_id < 100* using filter parameter?

Someone faced this problem before?
Thanks 1000

Comment: cdo umentation say it is : an array of customerCustomerEntity.  It is Entity so you can use any linq like : db.customerCustomerEntity.Where(x => x.customer_id < 100)

Comment: I need to filter results before save it in db; when I call for all results (with null as filter parameter) I get another exception, something like too many bytes..

Comment: Are you sure the message isn't "Too many parameters"?

Comment: No, it's Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 92 bytes)... but I cannot modify magento/server settings

Comment: You have an Out Of Memory error.  Before doing call it looks like you first have to fix a memory leak.